# Is it possible to have positive current coming from ground?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, conventions, batteries

Is it possible to have positive current coming from ground?

This is only in physics land and ignores all real-world situations.

Comment: "Is it legal to to have positive current coming from ground?" Yes. It is legal, ethical, and moral.

Comment: Voted to reopen because, IMO, OP is asking about underlying physics concepts (what does the ground symbol represent?) and is not asking us to perform any specific computations.

Comment: I was wondering if I could definitively prove my answer was wrong when ground is acting like a voltage source. From the answers, it seems that ground is an arbitrary description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can have positive current coming from ground, and you do not even need batteries connected to have that.

Take a conductor that is negatively charged and connect it to ground with a wire. This will create a new body composed of the first conductor, the wire, and the (reasonably conductive) Earth.
Electric charge will redistribute on this newly formed body and what we see is electrons flowing from the first conductor to ground via the wire.

[image: earthing a charged body]

Since conventional current has the opposite sign of electron current, the discharge of the earthed body happens with a positive (transient) current coming up from ground.

The Earth has a *massive* self-capacitance and the extra charge won't budge its potential (which by convention we can call "zero potential").
The large self capacitance of the Earth is what makes earthing 'special', meaning it's *something more* than attributing a reference value to the potential.

Note: the **self**-capacitance of the Earth is about 0.7 millifarad. Might seems not that big of a deal when compared with the values of **mutual** capacitance of ordinary capacitors. But as far as self capacitances go, it is enormous. As a matter of fact, the -45000 coulomb that are thought to reside on the surface of the Earth are spread out so thin on the surface that the surface charge density is only 80-90 femtocoulomb per square meter. This charge is responsbile for the 100 V/m eletric field near the surface in fair weather conditions. (Nearly the same charge, but positive, is spread out in the atmosphere in what is a giant spherical capacitor with local disuniformities that cause concentrated discharges.)

Answer (score 1):

Voltages in a circuit are only defined between two nodes. "Ground" is just some node that is arbitrarily chosen* as a reference point so that when we say, "voltage *at* node n" we actually are talking about the voltage *between* node n and ground.

There is no *physical* significance to the fact that some node in the circuit is called "ground."

---

Consider these two diagrams:

[image]

They both describe exactly the same circuit. The diagram on the left has two ground *symbols,* but in either case, there is only one ground *node.* It would be physically realized by a wire connecting one terminal of the resistor to the negative terminal of the voltage source (power supply.)

The diagram on the left shows current flowing *in* to one ground symbol and *out* of the other ground symbol, but in reality, the current flows *through* the one ground node. It flows from the resistor to the voltage source.

Same is true for your circuit. It shows three ground symbols, but there is only one ground node, and current flows through it.

---

* There are strong *practical* reasons why, in most circuit diagrams, one of the power supply rails (usually the negative if there is only one [*source*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source#Current_and_voltage_source_comparison)) is chosen for ground. But, it would not change the behavior of the circuit if you renamed that node to be something else, and you chose to call some other node "ground."

Your circuit contains not one, but *three* sources, so there really is no reason at all why any node should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get it now.

Ground may be the source of some current but it is still not a voltage source. The only reason there is current through a system with ground is because of the batteries elsewhere causing a difference in potential; there would be no current without the batteries.

Current coming from ground is legal since ground is only defined as having a potential difference of 0, meaning that ground is basically an infinite wire that can hold and give infinite electrons.

Comment: Yes. It is not a voltage source, but it can source and sink charge/current.

Comment: No, no, no, and yes, respectively. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I love hft's answer. It sounds like one for the lawyers, but the laws of science are unbreakable, so there would be no work for them. What I assume you are getting confused with is conventional current, which is said to go from positive to negative. About 500 years ago when they rubbed a piece of glass with a cloth, and got a spark, they assumed that electricity was jumping off the glass, and matched it up to the polarity of the first batteries. When they discovered electrons in the 19th century, they found that electrons were rubbed off the glass, and jumping back on. By then, it would have been too much trouble and too expensive to republish all the books and rewrite all the papers, so they still said current goes from positive to negative, but electrons go from negative to positive. If you are concerned about the arrow going up from earth, the ground is just another conductor. The current can go either way.

Comment: Conventional current flows _toward_ almost all ground symbols in the majority of practical circuit diagrams. OP is asking why the arrow points _away_ from one of the ground symbols in the given diagram.